# How can I add an "active" class to post title in a list of posts?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a Wordpress recipe blog that gives users recipes for "breakfast" and "lunch." Each recipe is a separate Wordpress custom post type tagged as either "breakfast" or "lunch." (I'm using tags, not categories for a specific reason I won't get into.) The custom post types are called "recipes."

If a user is on a post tagged "breakfast" they see a list of all other posts tagged "breakfast." I've created this list by querying (with WP_Query) all posts tagged "breakfast," and displaying the titles of those posts in a list. The titles also link to the respective posts so the user can jump to any "breakfast"-tagged post while reading a "breakfast"-tagged post.

My problem: How do I add a class of "active" to the post title that corresponds to the post I am currently reading? (So if I'm on the post with title "bacon," the title "bacon" in my list of "breakfast"-tagged posts should have a class of "active." Below is the code I'm using on my single.php page to generate my lists of posts by tags:

```
<?php if (has_tag( 'breakfast' )) { ?>
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recipes', 'tag' => 'breakfast') ); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
            <?php the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>' ); ?>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } elseif (has_tag( 'lunch' )) { ?>
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recipes', 'tag' => 'lunch') ); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
            <?php the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>' ); ?>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the custom queries, put the ID of the current post in a var:

```
$temp = get_the_ID();
```

Then, in your custom loop, check if the IDs match:

```
$class = ( $temp == get_the_ID() ) ? 'active' : '';
```

and apply the appropriate class to the title:

```
class="' . $class . '"
```